# Google HTTPS load balancer - Limits of URL MAPS

Tags: google-cloud-http-load-balancer

What is the limit of Host and Path rules in URL MAP . I am trying to deg=fine host and path rules in the URL MAPS .based on host and path the ELB will route to the correct backend .

Same host can have multiple path rules.